# can't startup after installation, only windows works

Tags: startup

I just install Ubuntu 14.04 but can not start up. Only Windows show up.

see the outputs of running boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12018765

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12018827

I think it is of EFI setting.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are running Win8 or Win10. If not let me know, but I'm going off of the assumption that you are. If this answer doesn't work, please provide your Windows version and the type of computer you have and I will edit my answer.

There are two things you need to do to get it working:

1) First, go into bios. The method to do this depends on what version of windows you're running, so I'll recommend you Google it. Then ensure that "**Secure Boot**" is **disabled** and that it is set to "**CSM Boot**" and not "**UEFI Boot**".

The bios also depends on what hardware you have, so try Googling it. Then,

2) Make sure you **Turn Off** your computer. Windows will typically go to sleep instead of turning off. Google this if you need help, but you should be able to shift-click the power button in the start menu and then hit the "**Shut Down**" option.

If will take longer than normal to shut down, but should take you to GRUB when you boot your computer back up.

Hopefully that works, let me know!

Comment: Yes, Win8/10. I have tried different Bios settings and now it is: 

Security>
Plat form Mode                  User
Secure Boot                       Disable
Secure Boot Control           Disable

Comment: Alright, so you've disabled "Secure Boot" and "Secure Boot Control"? I'm assuming that it didn't work so would you mind posting what type of computer your using so I can look at its BIOS options?

Comment: Yes, I disabled both of them. My Laptop is ASUS X550j. Should I remove and reinstall Ubuntu 14?

Comment: Before doing that, try the "Load CSM" option in the BIOS that is talked about in one of the answers [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=302197).
If that doesn't work can you still boot to the usb or CD that you installed linux off of? ( And which one did you install from?)

Comment: First, I upgrade to Win 10. Then, set/check BIOS. Tag Boot> Launch CSM: enable; Launch PXEUpROM policy: enable.  Tag Security> Secure Boot Menu> Secure Boot: disable; Secure Boot Control: disable. After then, boot on E2B USB and then removed and reinstalled Ubuntu 14, but still can not boot into Ubuntu but only Win 10.

Comment: The boot info was updated at   paste.ubuntu.com/12049822. Then, I used "Boot-Repair-Disk" on E2B USB again to repair, it said: "the boot of your PC is in Legacy mode, please change it to EFI mode...."  Then, got the boot info again at     paste.ubuntu.com/12049864

Comment: Then, I remove and installed Ubuntu-mate15 but still booted only win10. Then, make Boot-repair-disk CD, worked not. Finally, I made Boot-Repair-Disk USB drive (no more by E2B, Easy2Boot) and found it does have UEFI boot. It eventually works!